# How can i catch uninitialized variable exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

So if i have something like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello;
        System.out.println(hello);
    }

}
```

So this would obviously not work. But considering i have such a situation in a program, how can i catch such exception, can you please tell.

Thank you,

EDIT:

So if i have something like this:

```
class ABC{

   public static String myString;
   public ABC(String myString){
      myString = this.myString;
   }

   public static String getString(){
      return myString;
   }

}
```

and now if in another class, without calling the constructor of ABC i do like:

```
 ABC.getString();
```

This is what i am trying to say... you get it??

Comment: You can't have that situation in your program - it won't compile.

Comment: Ah okay. But if i have a situation where i initialize variable in constructor and later for it's getValue() i return this value. So what  will happen if that method is called without first initializing the value. So do i have to provide a default value or something in this case??

Comment: @Johndy: It sounds like you're talking about an *instance* variable. Please give an updated short but complete example.

Comment: @S.L.Barth but it works even without initilizing ABC, if it is defined as static it will still work

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'uninitialized variable exception in Java'. Your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others pointed out, the first case won't compile.

You should assign a value to the String. `null` or an empty string are the usual default values.

Consider carefully what would be a logical default value.
Better yet, consider why the code would encounter an uninitialized variable, determine what the value the variable *should* have (whether a default value or not), and modify your code accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i really didn't mean what the question statement says but i got my answer,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this class doesn't compile, so you don't need to catch it. :)